# asp.net mvc route conflicting with areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

Our asp.net mvc 4 application has a route defined as following

```
routes.MapCustomRoute(
            name: "Startup",
            url: "{area1}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Startup", action = "Index", param3 = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "namespaceofmaincontrollers" }
            );
```

We also have an area with the name "area1". We are getting http 404 error browsing to the route.

We have tried using routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; to no avail.

We want to hit the controller action Index of the StartupController defined in the main portion of our application .

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try adding area as a default: area = 'area1'

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that while area registration the namespaces were incorrect which was the cause of the problem. Once corrected our 404 errors disappeared.